# Floating Action Button Unwanted Behavior with Recycle view android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The behavior of FAB is unexpected. The images are in the link below

Can not find any help.. It does work sometime and sometime does not. 
Not being able to find actual problem
even tried to add dynamically  like

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) btnSubmitConfirm.getLayoutParams(); 
   params.setAnchorId(R.id.listWorkData);        
params.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | GravityCompat.END | Gravity.RIGHT;        
btnSubmitConfirm.setLayoutParams(params);
```

but dosen't work at allHere's the xml codeneed a solution guys

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/parentView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:background="@color/background"
android:clickable="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listWorkData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/ten" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnConfirmSubmitReport"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/thirty"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/listWorkData"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

[OK Condition Image][1]
[Not OK Condition Image][2]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D0XD.png  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ds2Gi.png

Comment: Remove app:layout_anchor and app:layout_anchorGravity

Comment: @Rohit what kind of suggestion is actually that?? I do need the FAB at the bottom of the recycleview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a small tweak to make it work as I needed
I simply added the listener to check if the recycler view is updated and made changes to FAB inside it.

The scenario was, the fab loaded before prior to the recycler view. So again needed to update the layout after the view is loaded

```
listWorkData.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            listWorkData.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) btnSubmitConfirm.getLayoutParams();
            lp.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | GravityCompat.END;
            btnSubmitConfirm.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    listWorkData.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this,

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/listWorkData"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

And check.

Comment: Really? I'm sure thats not my solution. I do want the FAB at the very right bottom.